# Connecting Java Gui to different implementations in different classes

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I'm making a simple java reaction game using java. Display is my class that initialises a gui:

public class Display  extends JFrame implements Gui{

```
//Connect gui to controller
//(This method will be called before ANY other methods)
public void connect(Controller controller){

}

    //Initialise the gui
public Display(){
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JButton coin = new JButton();
JButton goStop = new JButton();
JLabel prompt = new JLabel("Insert Coin", JLabel.CENTER);

setTitle("Reaction Game");
    setContentPane(panel);

coin.setIcon(new ImageIcon("coin.png"));
goStop.setIcon(new ImageIcon("GoButton.png"));

//setting layout of panel
panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(100, 20));
//adding buttons to panel
panel.add(prompt, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
panel.add(coin, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
panel.add(goStop, BorderLayout.LINE_END);


setSize(400,200);
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

}

What the buttons actually do is implemented in 2 different classes, Controller1 and Controller2 (which implement a Controller Class), each doing a different thing depending on which one we decide to use.

Controller1:

public class Controller1 implements Controller{

```
//Creating a constructor
public Controller1(){

}
   //Connect controller to gui
//(This method will be called before ANY other methods)
public void connect(Gui gui, Random rng){

}
```

}

Controller2:

public class Controller2 implements Controller{

```
//Creating a constructor
public Controller2(){

}
   //Connect controller to gui
//(This method will be called before ANY other methods)
public void connect(Gui gui, Random rng){

}
```

}

I was just wondering how i'd go about connecting the gui and controller.

Comment: You should code all what you say in words cause it's awful to read something like that.

Comment: I've added more code, hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom `ActionListener` for each button that executes the methods from either `Controller1` or `Controller2`. That way you can specify the methods that will be used in the `ActionListener` and assign them to a specific button (or other GUI component).

You can put the following in the `Display` constructor (of course, after `coin` and `goStop` have been initialized).

```
coin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Controller1 tempcontroller = new Controller1();

        tempcontroller.connect(this, new Random());
    }
});

goStop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Controller2 tempcontroller = new Controller2();

        tempcontroller.connect(this, new Random());
    }
});
```

Comment: So I would do this in both controller1 and 2? I've added some more code if that helps